# Remove manage password autofill from text box

Tags: reactjs

[image]I am new to react js,I see the manage password autofill on my forgot password textbox(google chrome browser),i dont want to show the manage password autofill to user

i have set autoComplete="off" for respective textbox but i still see manage password autofill

```html
<input className="form-control" id="email2" name="emailidOne" type="text" placeholder="forget password" value={this.state.fields.emailid} autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

i dont want to show manage password autofill(chrome browser) on respective texbox

Comment: Try change the input name, id and autofill to "diasbled" like:
<input className="form-control" id="the_email2" name="the_emailidOne" type="text" placeholder="forget password" value={this.state.fields.emailid} autoComplete="disabled" onChange={this.handleChange} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input className="form-control" id="email2" name="emailidOne" type="text" placeholder="forget password" value={this.state.fields.emailid} autoComplete="no-password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: remove your id as well name because chrome autofill try to populate with the help of id and name

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
autoComplete="new-password"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion